# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed. Express/MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I've gone through the several questions and answers. I have the jest.config.js as instructed by Mongoose docs to `testEnvironment: 'node'`. I close the connection to mongoose in afterAll. The test itself passes. Please help me to understand the root of the issue.

```
const  mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')


const api = supertest(app)

test('blogs are returned as json', async () => {
  await api
    .get('/api/blogs')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
})

afterAll( async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close()
} )
```

--detectOpenHandles points to the testfile and to the mongoose connection in app.js

> Timeout

```
   8 | test('blogs are returned as json', async () => {
   9 |   await api
> 10 |     .get('/api/blogs')
     |      ^
  11 |     .expect(200)
  12 |     .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
  13 | })
```

> TLSWRAP

```
  10 | ;(async () => {
  11 |   try {
> 12 |     await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI)
     |                    ^
  13 |     logger.info('connected to mongoDB')
  14 |   } catch(e) {
  15 |     logger.error('error connecting to mongoDB: ', e.message)
```

Comment: What you need to close is the mongoose connection which is opened by the express app. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/520

Comment: thanks for the link, I went through the conversation and tried different solutions but did't find a successful one for my case. Would you be able to pinpoint how would I close the express app connection in my testfile?

Comment: I added `console.log(mongoose.connection.readyState)` as a last line inside afterAll and it logs 0 (disconnected)